# JTable calculate sum of the last column

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jtable

I have a JTable witch implements TableModelListener, I have implemented the tableChanged(TableModelEvent event) methode, But I'm not able to detect the right column that was modified. I got col -1, while i'm editing the second or a specific column.

Here is my implementation of tableChanged(TableModelEvent event) methode:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


public class JTableTest extends JDialog{
    private JTable myTable ; 

    public JTableTest() {
        super();

        myTable = new JTable(new myTableModel());
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(myTable),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    class myTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModelListener{

        Object[][] donnees = {
                {"Johnathan", "Sykes","Natation"},
                {"Nicolas", "Van de Kampf","FOOTBALL" },
                {"Damien", "Cuthbert","TENNIS" },
                {"Corinne", "Valance","NATATION"},
                {"Emilie", "Schrödinger","FOOTBALL"},
                {"Delphine", "Duke","TENNIS"},
                {"Eric", "Trump","TENNIS"},
        };

        String[] entetes = {"Prénom", "Nom","SPORT"};

        public myTableModel() {
            addTableModelListener(this);
        }

         public int getRowCount() {
        return donnees.length;

    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return entetes.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return entetes[columnIndex];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return donnees[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent me) {
            // I wanna get the right column not -1
            System.out.println(me.getColumn());
            switch(me.getType()){
                case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                    System.out.println("Updating...");break;
                case TableModelEvent.INSERT:
                    System.out.println("Inserting...");break; 
                case TableModelEvent.DELETE:
                    System.out.println("Delete...");break;
                default :break ;
            }

         }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            donnees[row][col] = (String) value;
            fireTableDataChanged();
         }


        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return true; 
         }



}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new JTableTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }








}
```

Comment: It is returning the constant TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS. Have you checked event.getType() to make sure you are getting an UPDATE? If not then wrap your code in an if or switch.

Comment: i've added event.getType(), i got an update  but event.getColumn() still returning -1, while i'm change an active column( 1 or 2)

Comment: Could you add your table creation code? I've generally created JTables using a subclass of AbstractTableModel which allows you to override setValue. I find that easier than responding to events.

Comment: Won't solve your problem, but don't manually invoke "firstTableDataChanged()". It is the responsibility of the TableModel to invoke that method when the data is changed. I have never had a problem with a TableModelListener. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Remember the SSCCE should just simply display a message when data in column 3 is updated. We don't care about your real processing.

Comment: I have writed an sscce example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your original question how are we supposed to guess that you are using a custom TableModel? That is why you should always include a proper SSCCE with the question so we don't have to guess what you may or may not be doing.

Why are you using a custom TableModel? There is no need to create a custom model. The DefaultTableModel will do what your custom model does.

Anyway, the problem is indeed with your custom TableModel:

```
//fireTableDataChanged();
fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
```

You didn't change all the data. You only changed the data of one cell so fire the proper event.

Comment: No, this just a simulation of my real problem. I've customized the table model in order to make cells editable, allow the user to add  row witch are object not String type....etc.

Comment: @abdouamer, That can all be done with the DefaultTableModel. You override the isCellEditable(...) method, you don't create a whole new class.

Comment: you mean that i need to extends the DefaultTableModel ?

Answer (score 0):

The method [BigDecimal.add(BigDecimal)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add(java.math.BigDecimal)) returns a **BigDecimal**. It does not reassign the value.

You should use the following code to reassign `somme` value:

```
somme = somme.add((BigDecimal) getValueAt(i, 3));
```

Comment: okay, i fixed this, but this not acually the problem for that post, i want to detect when a value of the third column has been updated